# The type or namespace name `InteractionSourceUpdatedEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, libraries, hololens

I started a project from MR Design Lab which is interacting objects. but there are certain errors which are i am facing.

> **The type or namespace name** Focus does not exist in the namespace `HUX'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> **The type or namespace name** InteractionSourcePressType' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
>
> **The type or namespace name** InteractionSourceUpdatedEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Previously on the same settings i worked on different applications and it worked perfectly i dont know whats the problem

Script association is also getting lost again n again. Is that a bug in Unity ? 
any ideas ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: No i dont think so. There are some changes which is made by Unity from XR to VR its only a version change. and its still not working tho

Comment: UnityEngine.VR.WSA.* namespaces and classes are now UnityEngine.XR.WSA.* in Unity 2017.2. Also, if you are using Mixed Reality Toolkit from Microsoft (and maybe other packages), you would need to install latest Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0.16299.0) SDK.